# Close - Duplicate, when more recent question is more useful

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

Came across this in the review queue:  [Can I freeze cream?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116523/can-you-freeze-food-with-cream-in-it)

It was VTC - Duplicate of [Can I freeze bagna cauda (cream)?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/can-you-freeze-bagna-cauda-cream-basically)

Now, both these questions are rather simple, but they do have pretty specific answers.

I voted to close as it was a clear duplicate, but then I got to thinking.   Isn't the more recent question the better one in that it's more likely to be hit by a user searching for an answer?

What should be done in situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are quite right. Since nobody else has chimed in, I went ahead and closed it, placing the duplicates in the direction you suggested.